# Android AutoCompleteTextView showing wrong suggestions

Tags: java, android, textview, autocompletetextview

I had the AutoCompleteTextView working perfectly until I decided to use a custom adapter, that way I could customize the look of each row. Here is what now happens:

[image]

As you can see, the suggestion is wrong. What is happening is as I type, it shows the correct *number* of suggestions, but the actual names of them are the first ones in the list. So at this point it should show only one suggestion which is Texas A&M, but it instead just shows the first one in the list. Here is how I am implementing my adapter.

```
//setup filter
List<String> allCollegesList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(College c : MainActivity.collegeList)
{
    allCollegesList.add(c.getName());
}
AutoCompleteDropdownAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteDropdownAdapter(main, R.layout.list_row_dropdown, allCollegesList);
//the old way of using the adapter, which worked fine
//ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(main, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, allCollegesList);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As well as my actual adapter class:

```
public class AutoCompleteDropdownAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    MainActivity main;
    int rowLayout;
    List<String> allCollegesList;

    public AutoCompleteDropdownAdapter(MainActivity main, int rowLayout, List<String> allCollegesList) {
        super(main, rowLayout, allCollegesList);
        this.main = main;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.allCollegesList = allCollegesList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        try{

            if(convertView==null){
                // inflate the layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((MainActivity) main).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
            }

            // object item based on the position
            String college = allCollegesList.get(position);

            // get the TextView and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
            TextView collegeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dropDownText);
            collegeTextView.setText(college);
            collegeTextView.setTypeface(FontManager.light);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that when the `AutoCompleteTextView` calls the `getFilter` method of the `ArrayAdapter` a `Filter` is returned, that takes care of filtering the `ArrayAdapter`, but not your `allCollegesList`. When you type your first characters, the methods of the `Filter` are called and `ArrayAdapter` has filtered elements at the first positions (`0, 1, ...`). However when the `AutoCompleteTextView` uses your implementation to get the Views. You use your list as if no filtering was done and use the first elements of the unfiltered list.

You can filter your own list too by overriding the `getFilter` method of your adapter. But that would be more coding than necessary.

You can use the `ArrayAdapter`'s methods and not your own list, instead:

Use

```
String college = getItem(position);
```

instead of

```
String college = allCollegesList.get(position);
```

---

BTW:

you can get the context from `parent` too, using the `getContext()` method. That way you can decouple the Adapter from `MainActivity`.